# App Engine PHP72 Standard Environment, accessing env_variables in local environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, php-7.2

App Engine's official documentation on **[Migrating Your App from PHP 5.5 to PHP 7.2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences)** states:

> dev_appserver.py is not supported with the PHP 7.2 runtime. To test
>   your application and run it locally, you must download and install PHP
>   7.2 and set up a web server.

My problem is that running the app locally using PHP's web server does not automatically add the `env_variables` stored in `app.yaml` to the `$_SERVER` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses `symfony/yaml` to achieve what I'm after:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server') {
  $filePath = __DIR__ . '/../app.yaml';
  $array = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($filePath));
  $_SERVER = $_SERVER + $array['env_variables'];
}
```